# Python Pandas: How do I sumproduct by rows with an if condition?

Tags: python, pandas, sumproduct

I know there are some questions on Stack Overflow on Sumproduct but the solution are not working for me. I am also new to Python Pandas.

For each row, I want to do a sumproduct of certain columns only if column['2020'] !=0.
I used the below code, but get error:

**IndexError: ('index 2018 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 27', 'occurred at index 0')**

Pls help. Thank you

```
# df_copy is my dataframe

column_list=[2018,2019]

weights=[6,9]

def test(df_copy):


    if df_copy[2020]!=0:

        W_Avg=sum(df_copy[column_list]*weights)

    else:

        W_Avg=0


    return W_Avg

 
df_copy['sumpr']=df_copy.apply(test, axis=1)
```

**df_copy**

```
**|2020 | 2018 | 2019 | sumpr|**
|0    | 100  | 20   | 0    |
|1    | 30   | 10   | 270  |
|3    | 10   | 10   | 150  |
```

I am sorry if the table doesn't look like a table. I can't create a table properly in Stackoverflow.

Basically **for a particular row**, if

```
2020 = 2 ,
2018 =30 ,
2019 =10 ,

sumpr= 30 * 9 + 10*9 = 270
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column names are most likely **strings**, not integers.

To confirm it, run `df_copy.columns` and you should receive something like:

```
Index(['2020', '2018', '2019'], dtype='object')
```

(note apostrophes surrounding column names).

So change your column list to:

```
column_list = ['2018', '2019']
```

In your function change also the column name to a string:

```
df_copy['2020']
```

Then your code should run.

You can also run a more concise code:

```
df_copy['sumpr'] = np.where(df_copy['2020'] != 0, (df_copy[column_list]
    * weights).sum(axis=1), 0)
```